# Recycler View not adjusting to match parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

[image: Elements inside Recycler View not adjusting to match parent. As observed, list elements are occupying a fraction of fragment's width and not stretching to match parent.]

**I have used a fragment inside which recyler view is used to load list elements.**

Following is the layout file for fragment.

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/languagebar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:liftOnScroll="true">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="5dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">
            <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                app:flexWrap="wrap"
                app:justifyContent="flex_start">

                <Button
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonEnglish"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_yellow_white"
                    android:onClick="outletTypeClick"
                    android:text="English"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_80" />

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonHindi"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_yellow_white"
                    android:onClick="outletTypeClick"
                    android:text="Hindi"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_80" />

            </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:scrollingCache="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

*Following is the initialization of recylerview inside fragment -*

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Defines the xml file for the fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timeline1, parent, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    RecyclerLinearLayoutManager recyclerLinearLayoutManager =
            new RecyclerLinearLayoutManager(rootView.getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerLinearLayoutManager);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

*Here is the code from viewadapter -*

```
@Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        switch (viewType) {
            case TITLE:
                View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_timeline_title, viewGroup, false);
                v1.setMinimumWidth(viewGroup.getMinimumWidth());
                viewHolder = new TitleViewHolder(v1);
                break;
            case HEADLINE:
                View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_timeline_headline, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder1(v2);
                break;
            .....
        }

        return viewHolder;
    }
```

**Adding row item's xml.**

item-layout-1 (heterogeneous view) -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@color/grey_10" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                android:tint="@color/pink_400"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/shape_round_solid" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            app:cardElevation="1dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_xxlarge"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_xlarge" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/item_itinerary_text1"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="casual"
                                android:text="Aman Weds Shreya"
                                android:textAlignment="center"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                                android:textColor="@color/red_500"
                                android:textSize="40sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/item_itinerary_image1"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:foreground="@color/overlay_light_20"
                    android:src="@drawable/wedding_logo" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

item-layout-2 (heterogeneous view)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyt_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@color/grey_10" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                android:tint="@color/light_green_400"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/shape_round_solid" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            app:cardElevation="1dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                        android:id="@+id/item_itinerary_image1"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_xlarge"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_xlarge"
                        android:foreground="@color/overlay_light_20"
                        android:src="@drawable/hotel_highwayking"
                        app:civ_shadow="true"
                        app:civ_shadow_radius="0"
                        app:civ_border="false" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_large"
                        android:layout_height="0dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/item_itinerary_text1"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Refreshments"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                                android:textColor="@color/light_blue_400"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/item_itinerary_text2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:text="30 mins stay"
                            android:textColor="@color/grey_20"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/spacing_middle" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_itinerary_text3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
                    android:text="Morning Refreshment at Hotel Highway King, Jaipur ."
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_60" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**In reference to the attached image -**
When I set image and text in layout file itself, it is occupying more width(as shown in attached screenshot). Whereas when I load the image and text via code, view renders to 20% of width.
Also, the width of the recyler-view-section(as in below image) remains same in both landscape and portrait mode.
Above observations looks like recyler-view width is rendering as wrap-content and not as match_parent. But I am not able to understand why this is happening as I have not used that logic in my code.

Comment: Post your complete xml

Comment: is your item xml layout set to wrap_content ?

Comment: And post your recycle view row

Comment: @kam1234 have added xml layout for 2 item rows.

Comment: @VivekMishra, no width has been set to match_parent. Check edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are loading fragment in the activity, check your FrameLayout container, you could have set its width to wrap_content, please change it to match_parent.